# Batch email sent 201 Error too many soql queries

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm getting too many SOQL queries 201 error when executing the batch class. I'm not even using any SOQL query inside for loop so I don't understand why am I getting this error. It is urgent any help is greatly appreciated.

```
global class autoOutreachEmails implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{

    List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstMsgs = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();


    String outreachStage = 'Outreach';
    String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, CloseDate, Owner.Email, Referral_Partners__c, Full_Policy_Type_Name__c, Last_Activity_Subject__c, Owner.Name, Contact_Name__c, Disable_Automatic_Emails__c, OwnerId, RecordType.Name, Next_Contact_Date__c, Activity_Type__c, Contact_Email__c FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = \'Outreach\' AND Disable_Automatic_Emails__c = false  AND Next_Contact_Date__c <= Today AND Contact_Email__c != null LIMIT 10000';


    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }   

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope){


   //List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstMsgs = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();


        for(Opportunity o : (Opportunity[]) scope)
        {     
            System.debug('system' +scope.size());
            System.debug('system' +scope);
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            Opportunity oppRecord = new Opportunity();  

            Task createTask = new Task();
            String taskRecordId = Schema.SObjectType.Task.getRecordtypeInfosByName().get('ROC Task').getRecordtypeId();

            if( o.Next_Contact_Date__c <= Date.Today()){

                msg.setSubject(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.NGOutreach5WORK, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getSubject());
                msg.setPlainTextBody(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.NGOutreach5WORK, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getPlainTextBody());
                msg.setSenderDisplayName(o.Owner.Name);
                msg.setSaveAsActivity(true);
                msg.setWhatId(o.Id);
                msg.setReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                msg.setBccSender(false);
                msg.setUseSignature(false);
                msg.setInReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                msg.setToAddresses(new List<String>{o.Contact_Email__c});
                lstMsgs.add(msg); 

                oppRecord.Activity_Type__c = 'Attempted Contact 5';
                oppRecord.Last_Activity_Subject__c =  'Attempted Contact 5 - auto email';
                oppRecord.Id = o.Id;

                oppList.add(oppRecord);
                createTask.RecordTypeId = taskRecordId;
                createTask.Subject = 'Outreach Attempted Contact 5 - automated Email';
                createTask.WhatId = o.Id;
                createTask.ActivityDate = Date.Today();
                createTask.Opportunity_Stage__c = 'Outreach';
                createTask.Activity_Types__c = 'Attempted Contact 5';
                createTask.ActivityDate = Date.Today();
                createTask.Status = 'Completed';
                system.debug('TASK CREATE' +createTask);
                taskList.add(createTask);
            }

            if(  o.RecordType.Name == 'WORK' && o.Activity_Type__c == 'Attempted Contact 5'){

                msg.setSubject(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.NGOutreach6WORK, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getSubject());
                msg.setPlainTextBody(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.NGOutreach6WORK, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getPlainTextBody());
                msg.setSenderDisplayName(o.Owner.Name);
                msg.setSaveAsActivity(true);
                msg.setWhatId(o.Id);
                msg.setReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                msg.setUseSignature(false);
                msg.setInReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                msg.setToAddresses(new List<String>{o.Contact_Email__c});
                lstMsgs.add(msg); 

                oppRecord.Activity_Type__c = 'Attempted Contact 6';
                oppRecord.Last_Activity_Subject__c =  'Attempted Contact 6 - auto email';
                oppRecord.CloseDate = Date.Today();
                oppRecord.Id = o.Id;
                oppList.add(oppRecord);
                createTask.RecordTypeId = taskRecordId;
                createTask.Subject = 'Outreach Attempted Contact 6 - automated Email';
                createTask.WhatId = o.Id;
                createTask.Opportunity_Stage__c = 'Outreach';
                createTask.ActivityDate = Date.Today();
                createTask.Activity_Types__c = 'Attempted Contact 6';
                createTask.Status = 'Completed';
                system.debug('TASK CREATE' +createTask);
                taskList.add(createTask);
            }

            if( o.RecordType.Name == 'Commercial' && o.Activity_Type__c == 'Attempted Contact 4' && o.Next_Contact_Date__c <= Date.Today()){

                msg.setSubject(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.NGOutreach5Comml, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getSubject());
                msg.setPlainTextBody(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.NGOutreach5Comml, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getPlainTextBody());
                msg.setSenderDisplayName(o.Owner.Name);
                msg.setSaveAsActivity(true);
                msg.setWhatId(o.Id);
                msg.setReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                msg.setUseSignature(false);
                msg.setInReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                msg.setToAddresses(new List<String>{o.Contact_Email__c});
                lstMsgs.add(msg); 

                oppRecord.Activity_Type__c = 'Attempted Contact 5';
                oppRecord.Last_Activity_Subject__c =  'Attempted Contact 5 - auto email';
                oppRecord.Id = o.Id;
                oppList.add(oppRecord);
                createTask.RecordTypeId = taskRecordId;
                createTask.Subject = 'Outreach Attempted Contact 5 - automated Email';
                createTask.WhatId = o.Id;
                createTask.Opportunity_Stage__c = 'Outreach';
                createTask.Activity_Types__c = 'Attempted Contact 5';
                createTask.ActivityDate = Date.Today();
                createTask.Status = 'Completed';
                system.debug('TASK CREATE' +createTask);
                taskList.add(createTask); 
            }

            if(o.RecordType.Name == 'Commercial' && o.Activity_Type__c == 'Attempted Contact 5' && o.Next_Contact_Date__c <= Date.Today()){

                msg.setSubject(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.NGOutreach6Comml, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getSubject());
                msg.setPlainTextBody(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.NGOutreach6Comml, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getPlainTextBody());
                msg.setSenderDisplayName(o.Owner.Name);
                msg.setSaveAsActivity(true);
                msg.setWhatId(o.Id);
                msg.setReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                msg.setUseSignature(false);
                msg.setInReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                msg.setToAddresses(new List<String>{o.Contact_Email__c});
                lstMsgs.add(msg); 

                oppRecord.Activity_Type__c = 'Attempted Contact 6';
                oppRecord.Last_Activity_Subject__c =  'Attempted Contact 6 - auto email';
                oppRecord.CloseDate = Date.Today();
                oppRecord.Id = o.Id;
                oppList.add(oppRecord);
                createTask.RecordTypeId = taskRecordId;
                createTask.Subject = 'Outreach Attempted Contact 6 - automated Email';
                createTask.WhatId = o.Id;
                createTask.Opportunity_Stage__c = 'Outreach';
                createTask.Activity_Types__c = 'Attempted Contact 6';
                createTask.ActivityDate = Date.Today();
                createTask.Status = 'Completed';
                system.debug('TASK CREATE' +createTask);
                taskList.add(createTask);   

            }

            if(o.RecordType.Name == 'WORK' && o.Activity_Type__c == 'Attempted Contact 4' && o.Next_Contact_Date__c <= Date.Today()){

                msg.setSubject(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.GustoOutreach5WORK, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getSubject());
                msg.setPlainTextBody(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.GustoOutreach5WORK, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getPlainTextBody());
                msg.setSenderDisplayName(o.Owner.Name);
                msg.setSaveAsActivity(true);
                msg.setWhatId(o.Id);
                msg.setReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                msg.setUseSignature(false);
                msg.setInReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                msg.setToAddresses(new List<String>{o.Contact_Email__c});
                lstMsgs.add(msg);

                    oppRecord.Activity_Type__c = 'Attempted Contact 5';
                    oppRecord.Last_Activity_Subject__c =  'Attempted Contact 5 - auto email';
                    oppRecord.Id = o.Id;
                        oppList.add(oppRecord);
                        createTask.RecordTypeId = taskRecordId;
                        createTask.Subject = 'Outreach Attempted Contact 5 - automated Email';
                        createTask.WhatId = o.Id;
                        createTask.Opportunity_Stage__c = 'Outreach';
                        createTask.Activity_Types__c = 'Attempted Contact 5';
                        createTask.ActivityDate = Date.Today();
                        createTask.Status = 'Completed';
                system.debug('TASK CREATE' +createTask);
                        taskList.add(createTask);      

               }

             if(o.RecordType.Name == 'WORK' && o.Activity_Type__c == 'Attempted Contact 5' && o.Next_Contact_Date__c <= Date.Today()){

                 msg.setSubject(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.GustoOutreach6WORK, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getSubject());
                 msg.setPlainTextBody(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.GustoOutreach6WORK, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getPlainTextBody());
                 msg.setSenderDisplayName(o.Owner.Name);
                 msg.setSaveAsActivity(true);
                 msg.setWhatId(o.Id);
                 msg.setReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                 msg.setUseSignature(false);
                 msg.setInReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                 msg.setToAddresses(new List<String>{o.Contact_Email__c});
                 lstMsgs.add(msg);  

                 oppRecord.Activity_Type__c = 'Attempted Contact 6';
                 oppRecord.Last_Activity_Subject__c =  'Attempted Contact 6 - auto email';
                 oppRecord.CloseDate = Date.Today();
                 oppRecord.Id = o.Id;
                 oppList.add(oppRecord);
                 createTask.RecordTypeId = taskRecordId;
                 createTask.Subject = 'Outreach Attempted Contact 6 - automated Email';
                 createTask.WhatId = o.Id;
                 createTask.Opportunity_Stage__c = 'Outreach';
                 createTask.Activity_Types__c = 'Attempted Contact 6';
                 createTask.ActivityDate = Date.Today();
                 createTask.Status = 'Completed';
                 system.debug('TASK CREATE' +createTask);
                 taskList.add(createTask);      

             }

              if(o.RecordType.Name == 'Commercial' && o.Activity_Type__c == 'Attempted Contact 4' && o.Next_Contact_Date__c <= Date.Today()){

                  msg.setSubject(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.GustoOutreach5Comml, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getSubject());
                  msg.setPlainTextBody(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.GustoOutreach5Comml, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getPlainTextBody());
                  msg.setSenderDisplayName(o.Owner.Name);
                  msg.setSaveAsActivity(true);
                  msg.setWhatId(o.Id);
                  msg.setReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                  msg.setUseSignature(false);
                  msg.setInReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                  msg.setToAddresses(new List<String>{o.Contact_Email__c});
                  lstMsgs.add(msg); 

                  oppRecord.Activity_Type__c = 'Attempted Contact 5';
                  oppRecord.Last_Activity_Subject__c =  'Attempted Contact 5 - auto email';
                  oppRecord.Id = o.Id;
                  oppList.add(oppRecord);
                  createTask.RecordTypeId = taskRecordId;
                  createTask.Subject = 'Outreach Attempted Contact 5 - automated Email';
                  createTask.WhatId = o.Id;
                  createTask.Opportunity_Stage__c = 'Outreach';
                  createTask.Activity_Types__c = 'Attempted Contact 5';
                  createTask.ActivityDate = Date.Today();
                  createTask.Status = 'Completed';
                  system.debug('TASK CREATE' +createTask);
                  taskList.add(createTask);      
              }

              if( o.RecordType.Name == 'Commercial' && o.Activity_Type__c == 'Attempted Contact 5' && o.Next_Contact_Date__c <= Date.Today()){

               //Not decided yet if All Partners Comml template will be used for Gusto.
                  msg.setSubject(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.NGOutreach6Comml, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getSubject());
                  msg.setPlainTextBody(Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(label.NGOutreach6Comml, o.OwnerId, o.Id).getPlainTextBody());
                  msg.setSenderDisplayName(o.Owner.Name);
                  msg.setSaveAsActivity(true);
                  msg.setWhatId(o.Id);
                  msg.setReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                  msg.setUseSignature(false);
                  msg.setInReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
                  msg.setToAddresses(new List<String>{o.Contact_Email__c});
                  lstMsgs.add(msg); 

                  oppRecord.Activity_Type__c = 'Attempted Contact 6';
                  oppRecord.Last_Activity_Subject__c =  'Attempted Contact 6 - auto email';
                  oppRecord.CloseDate = Date.Today();
                  oppRecord.Id = o.Id;
                  oppList.add(oppRecord);
                  createTask.RecordTypeId = taskRecordId;
                  createTask.Subject = 'Outreach Attempted Contact 6 - automated Email';
                  createTask.WhatId = o.Id;
                  createTask.Opportunity_Stage__c = 'Outreach';
                  createTask.Activity_Types__c = 'Attempted Contact 6';
                  createTask.ActivityDate = Date.Today();
                  createTask.Status = 'Completed';
                  system.debug('TASK CREATE' +createTask);
                  taskList.add(createTask);      

               }



      }

          System.debug('lstMsgsz8888'+lstMsgs);
        if(!lstMsgs.isEmpty()) {
            try{

                Messaging.sendEmail(lstMsgs);
                if(!taskList.isEmpty()){
                    database.insert(taskList, false);

                }
                if(!oppList.isEmpty()){
                    database.update(oppList, false);

                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex) {

                System.debug('Message: '+ ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

  }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){





   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate` **does** use a SOQL statement. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm) says:

> Executing the renderStoredEmailTemplate method counts toward the SOQL governor limit as one query.

Do not execute this method in a loop, as it counts as a query.

You might consider using setTemplateId instead, which should work for most normal purposes. Usually, one uses renderStoredEmailTemplate because they want to provide a preview of the message.

Also, as an aside:

```
msg.setInReplyTo(o.Owner.Email);
```

This is not the correct use of InReplyTo. You should use this method only if you are replying to another message that has a message ID. Placing an Email in this field is likely going to do the Wrong Thing by email clients.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will correct the code accordingly. But, according to my requirement I had to use renderStoredEmailTemplate instead of TemplateId. 
Interestingly, when I am reducing the batch size to 20 or 1 it is not giving any error.